# How do I save the output of a system command in a variable and print to file?

Tags: perl

I'm doing a wget and would like to have the response saved to a variable like so....

```
$myresp = `wget yadda yadda`;
```

Note, I'm not trying to save what comes back from the wget into the variable... just the STDERR (or whatever buffer it uses) that normally prints back out to the prompt when you use wget.  I see the output when I run the perl manually, but I want to have it logged... I know it's some sort of cryptic 2&>1 type of thingie, but can't find it and thought I'd ask here...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$r = `wget yadda yadda 2>&1`
```

will capture stdout and stderr in `$r`.

Comment: np :). all you had to do was swap the `&` and the `>`